# dd restore windows from MBR to smaller partition after installing OpenSUSE in UEFI, no secure boot

Tags: boot, partition, lvm, opensuse, uefi

Can I copy a windows partition with 30% actually used space from a MBR drive onto a UEFI drive even though the partition is half the size and will cut off the end of the copy? Will a windows startup repair fix the cut off partition?

First drive sda1 Windows, sda2 ext2 boot, sda3 physical volume for opensuse

Second drive sda1 uefi, sda2 opensuse physical volume, sda3 truncated Windows backup partition

Comment: I dont know exactly why they do this, try to be a bit more specific, what you do with dd (the command), and what you are you trying to do now. Write some examples... of the command what you expect, and what you are getting! I hope this helps! And remember that is not the right forum to learn about UEFI or windows, only unix & linux questions are allowed! So start the topic showing what you do with dd, what it does, and what you expect... try to do not show feelings, it makes your question harder to read.

Comment: How is that? Ty!

Comment: The thing is that i am not understanding the sequence of your steps (maybe because of my poor english)... you start saying that you are doing a experience with UEFI, why should I care?, i just want to know what is the problem with dd (unix & linux related!), what you are doing in a specific doing... ex: I am doing a backup of a partition with EFI filesystem, and it does not restore properly, why? What am i missing? for example! Maybe its my fault as i say, i just dont undervoted you!

Comment: I understand. I am waiting...

Comment: Why not just use clonezilla to make a clone of windows, then restore/dump it to whatever partition you want?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about behavior of Windows startup repair.

Comment: anything like this is a job for [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: @KyleH, please do not deface your post(s). This Q had an accepted Answer, which subsequently made no sense when you edited the Q. I have rolled the Q back to the previous version.

Comment: Delete it, i couldn't delete it which is what I'd do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a very bad idea.......unless you first convert the Windows to EFI like in this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/447686/how-to-boot-windows-8-from-a-legacy-mbr-partition-in-uefi-mode-via-grub

I am not sure about Windows and how this is related to Unix & Linux, but if you are talking about **dd** command you can do something like this:

sda2 = Windows partition (defragmented)

sdb3 = Windows partition with half size on the destination

```
dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sdb1
```

Yes it will stop when there is no more size available, and chkdsk will be able to fix that. (i am not 100% sure about chkdsk, but i see something like this before)

EFI uses a special partition with some loader files, you must copy they to, to the EFI partition from the old HD to the newer hard drive.

Comment: Linux is my primary os and just trying to get Windows back up as secondary with dd. Thank you

Comment: I think that is not the right way! DD will just copy the partition! it will not able to make your old MBR os to boot into a EFI environment. I am thinking about your problem, can you add to your question your partition layout?

Comment: In both hard drives...